# Alias for active pattern?

Tags: f#, alias

I have the following definition in module `Helper`.

```
module Helper

let (|InvariantEqualLooooongName|_|) (str : string) arg =
    if String.Compare(str, arg, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) = 0 then Some()
    else None
```

And I want to use it in another module.

```
let rec MyFunc .... = 
  let alias = Helper.InvariantEqualLooooongName // Error: The value, constructor, namespace or type 'InvariantEqualLooooongName' is not defined

  match a with 
  | alias "xxx" :: tail -> .....
  | alias "yyyy" :: tail -> ....
  | alias "zzzz" :: tail -> ...
  | alias "123" :: tail -> ...
```

However, it got the error of

> The value, constructor, namespace or type 'InvariantEqualLooooongName' is not defined

How to define the alias for active pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an alias for active pattern like this:

```
let alias = Helper.(|InvariantEqualLooooongName|_|)
```

But I believe you cannot use it in `match` expression because it will not be recognized without special symbols. To be able to use an alias you have to define it like this:

```
let (|Alias|_|)  = Helper.(|InvariantEqualLooooongName|_|)
```